# why is selenium reaching timeout when the element is there

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, webdriverwait

i have a problem code below where the element becomes visible and is not clicked. i tried both css selectors and the xpath.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


PROXY = "socks5://184.178.172.13:15311"  # IP:PORT or HOST:PORT

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)

driver.get('https://nitrogensports.eu/sport/tennis/starting-soon')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
table = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="modal-welcome-new-button"]')))
table.click()
table = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[class="div.events-result-set"]')))
print("finished")
time.sleep(30)
driver.close()
```

Comment: Have you tried By.id instead of xpath?

Comment: In your case, the element is getting visible but not able to click. So, you have to wait until that element is not getting clickable. `wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, 'xpath_of_element')))`. and then click the element.

Comment: just to be clear i am getting a timeout exception. i have tried by id as well.

Comment: `element becomes visible and is not clicked` which element exactly? Update the question with the relevant HTML please.

Answer (score 1):

As per your question the element identified as `(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="modal-welcome-new-button"]')` is not getting clicked.

Once the wait is over and the element is identified and returned back, moving forward as you are invoking `click()` method so instead of using the [expected_conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) method `presence_of_element_located` you need to use the method [`element_to_be_clickable`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable) as follows :

```
driver.get('https://nitrogensports.eu/sport/tennis/starting-soon')
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='party-button highlightable-button highlighted' and @id='modal-welcome-new-button']"))).click()
```

Comment: this doesn't solve the problem, i have updated my code and am now still getting the timeout error i was before, the element is not found but i have tried by id too. its definitely the correct id and xpath